# Multiple Form Submits using the same Function

Tags: javascript, html, forms

I have a form that is using a function like

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        $("#form1").submit(function() {
```

But I have 2 other forms that I'd like to use the same function if/when they submit, how would I write that?

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        $("#form1").submit(function(), 
        $("#form2").submit(function(), 
        $("#form3").submit(function() {
```

Thanks

Comment: Your question is unclear.

Comment: Hmm... I have a few forms that on submit I want to use the same function, how would I write the on submit to trigger that function if any one of them were to be submitted?

Comment: Is this all you're looking for???? 
        $("#form1").submit(customFunction());
        $("#form2").submit(customFunction());

Comment: Have the same function all forms, and have that function submit all three forms.

Comment: jcruz - Maybe? So function customFunction () { codecode } and then $("#form1").submit(customFunction()); $("#form2").submit(customFunction()); ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to just do this:

```
$("#form1, #form2, #form3").submit(function() {
    formid = this.id;
    console.log('Processing form [' +formid+ ']');
    ...etc...
```

Any of the specified IDs will trigger that submit function.

Using the `formid` var, you can fine-tune any form-specific mods within the function.

Comment: This was more what I was looking for, just a way to write it the most simplistically. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

If I understand, you want to share a function for various submit event handlers. This is fairly simple:

```
function submitHandler() {
   // handler stuff here.
}
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#form1").submit(submitHandler);
    $("#form2").submit(submitHandler);
    $("#form3").submit(submitHandler);
}
```

and alternative, if you want to handle all forms, is to specify which forms in the jquery selector.  You can do this for all forms on the page:

```
$(document).on('submit','form', function() { });
```

or, if you just add a class name to the forms you want to use it on:

```
$(document).on('submit','.formclass', function() { });
```

Answer (score 0):

You can pass the id of the form to submit them separately.

This code will allow you to have as many forms as you like without having to update the JS.

```js
function submitForm(id) {
  $("#" + id).submit(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    for (let i = 0; i < e.target.length - 1; i++) {
      console.log(e.target[i].name, e.target[i].value);
    }
  });
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="form1">
   <input name="name">
   <button onClick="submitForm('form1')">Submit</button>
</form>
<form id="form2">
   <input name="name">
   <button onClick="submitForm('form2')">Submit</button>
</form>
<form id="form3">
   <input name="name">
   <button onClick="submitForm('form3')">Submit</button>
</form>
```

Comment: submit is a handler to handle when the form is submitted. It doesn't actually submit the form.

Comment: Thats correct, the OP hasn't told us what they are doing with the data. This will allow the OP to send/manipulate/validate the data inside the function. Would be good to get some feedback from the OP TBH.

Comment: i don't think it does. I creates a handler for submit when the button is pressed, and handler would never get called because there is no way to submit the form.

Answer (score 0):

By `JQuery` you can use the below function `$("form").submitNow()` with any form element.

```js
$.fn.submitNow = function() {
  var form = $(this);
  // handle form element
  console.log(this.id, this.action);
  $(this).submit();
}
//use it
$("form").submitNow();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<form action="./action1" id="action1">
  <input type="submit" value="form1" />
</form>
<form action="./action2" id="action2">
  <input type="submit" value="form2" />
</form>
<form action="./action3" id="action3">
  <input type="submit" value="form3" />
</form>
```